# How can I change the name of a Notebook or Section?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Currently it's possible to change a Page's name using the [PATCH Page API](http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/patch-pages).

Anyone knows how to change the name of a Section or Notebook using the REST API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST API as of 10/22/15 don't support renaming of sections/notebooks. Only renaming page title is supported. But we'll take the feedback and put in in our backlog. 
Thanks